# SQL using SUM in CASE in SUM

Tags: sql

I had this query select

```
sum(CASE WHEN kpi.average >= temp.average THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recordOrder,
```

which worked fine, but I had to change it to this

```
sum(CASE WHEN sum(kpi.averageUse) / sum(kpi.averageTotal) >= temp.average THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recordOrder,
```

These queries have to get number of rows, where some value (average) is greater than average from TEMP table. But in the second query I have more accurate data (weighted average).
but I am getting error 
**1111 invalid use of group function**
Any ideas how to write SUM in CASE in SUM?
Thanks!

Comment: which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: update your question and add  all the query code ..  (not only a part)

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just non-sensical because you have nested sum functions:

```
sum(CASE WHEN sum(kpi.averageUse) / sum(kpi.averageTotal) >= temp.average THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recordOrder,
```

Without seeing your larger query, it is not possible to know what you really intend.  But I would speculate that you don't want the internal `sum()`s:

```
sum(CASE WHEN (skpi.averageUse / kpi.averageTotal) >= temp.average THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS recordOrder,
```